# How does % lifesteal works?

Tags: torchlight-2

I have some set items which give me `20% Health stolen` properties. How exactly does that lifesteal works, does it heal me for 20% of my weapons DPS per hit, 20% of the damage that was actually done per hit, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means it heals you for 20% of the Damage actually done to the monsters.

If you hit for 100 Damage you get healed 20 HP.

Comment: Do you know if it's only for auto-attack?

Comment: For the best of my knowledge its only for weapon damage/auto attack. I haven't seen skill damage triggering life-steal.